# .net 4 WCF Routing Service + REST

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to use the new WCF routing serice in WCF 4 for REST based services? I have something similar to a reverse proxy in mind. Basically I have a number of selfhosted rest based serivces which I want to expose via IIS with the same base url and port. The routing should be done by the last part of the url. I'm absolutly new to thw WCF routing service, so forgive me if that's a silly question, but I couldn't find any information about that on the web.

I have tried something like this (where serivce1/2 are the selfhosted services):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RoutingBehavior">
                <routing routeOnHeadersOnly="false" filterTableName="RoutingTable"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="RoutingBehavior" name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService">
            <endpoint address="myservices" contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <routing>
        <filterTables>
            <filterTable name="RoutingTable">
                <add filterName="service1Filter" priority="0" endpointName="service1"/>
                <add filterName="service2Filter" priority="0" endpointName="service2"/>
            </filterTable>
        </filterTables>
        <filters>
            <filter name="service1Filter" filterType="MatchAll"/>
            <filter name="service2Filter" filterType="MatchAll"/>
        </filters>
    </routing>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://somehost:8888/test/service1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="*" name="service1"/>
        <endpoint address="http://somehost:8732/test/service2" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="*" name="service2"/>
    </client>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I'm getting an endpoint not found exception. http://somehost:8888/test/service1 ist the base address of the selfhosted service and not the actual endpoint. Can I do routing based on the base address or (if rest routing is possible) must I add a route for every endpoint?

Comment: I think that would probably a missuse of the WCF routing service. I will use a "real" reverse proxy like ARR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a reverse proxy (in my case arr). I don't konw if using the WCF routing service for this purpose is possible, but it's probably a misuse.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on this fine piece of advice, I had to install the ARR extension, then enable proxy in iis to allow url rewrites to other hosts, then create the rewrite rule in my wcf routing service web.config so that both soap and straight html gets are handled somewhat transparently. For less trivial web content than mine some outbound rules would probably be required.

Answer (score 1):

Routing Service is only available for SOAP requests. To use routing with RESTful WCF you need to setup your routes using System.Web.Routing similar to MVC routing.